# Operating on different elements of std::vector in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, parallel-processing

Say I have a `std::vector<Object*>`.  The vector is large ( > 1000 elements) and each `Object*` needs to have extensive computation done on it.  The for loop that runs each the computation on each element then, can be easily parallelized. In fact, I could process all 1000 elements in parallel for maximum speedup ("embarrassingly parallel?")

Now I'm wondering 2 things:

1)  Is it safe to read and write to *different elements* of a `std::vector` without a lock? (***not*** modifying the vector itself!)

2)  Are there easy ways or conventions or patterns to follow to cut a for loop and dispatch to threads?

Comment: Mine two cents for 2) use for_each: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

Comment: @freerider: no parallelization

Comment: 2: I like tbb (http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) to parallelize data processings. Take a look at the `parallel_for`.

Comment: Windows has extremely good threading facilities.  You can begin with the [CreateThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682456(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes

2) You can use OpenMP to paralellize vector handling. If you are working with Microsoft VC++ 2010, Concurrency library has parallel_for and parallel_for_each algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

For 1, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372258/are-stl-container-classes-of-same-type-thread-safe/7372354#7372354):

> **§ 23.2.2 Container data races**
>
> 2/ Notwithstanding (17.6.5.9), implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same sequence, excepting `vector<bool>`, are modified concurrently.

Obviously this is C++11 (as C++98/03 made no mention of threads), however most implementations already comply.

I am afraid I don't know any convention. OpenMP could probably automate this.

To do it manually, I would probably use a queue-like system, as not all objects may require the same time, you could have one thread finish well after the others if you split in "equal" portions, whereas a queue feeding the threads would alleviate this issue by maximizing the parallelism up until the very end.

Comment: I thought that excepting "vector" was astonishingly inconvenient, glad it was just an HTML/formatting issue :-)

Comment: @Steve: ooops... copy/paste does not preserve formatting, I fear :( Thanks for patching!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS 2010 you can use the [Parallel Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434652.aspx) library to achieve the multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using g++, you can use gnu parallel mode http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html
using the standard stl algorithms in combination with lambda's which are auto parallelized.